# How can I know when a callback is executed

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, callback

So, what I really want to know, if it's possible, is how I can know when a callback is executed or how can I trigger and event from it or how can I use a callback to send a value when it's executed, in Angular using TypeScript.

I know how callbacks works and due to their asynchronous nature this thing might not be possible, but I hope maybe there is a workaround which I haven't found yet. I have a function like this:

```
abcCallback() {
  // code
}
```

which executes when I do a specific action (this action is not relevant for this question because I'm using a library and the context is different). The problem is that I cannot use variables or observables inside the function to send an event for example, or to change the value of a variable in order to know if the function has been executed.

The only way I can know if the callback is executed is by printing messages from inside the function, but I want to be able to know from the outside of the function if that callback has been executed.

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough and feel free to ask any additional questions.

Comment: Your question is too vague for anyone to be able to provide a sufficient answer. Describe your actual use case and someone can probably help. I also suggest reading this: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/README.md

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a static properties:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  static flag = false;
[...]
```

and in your callBack:

```
abcCallback() {
  MyComponent.flag = true;
}
```

Pay attention that if you have to use this property in HTML you have to implement a getter

Comment: But it's possible to send a static variable to another component?

Comment: In all your application you can import and use MyComponent and use MyComponent.flag

Comment: I managed to do this using static variables. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add some private flag just before the return statement of method execution, e.g.

```
abcCallback() {
  // code 
  abcCallback.__executed__ =  true;
}
```

Then you can get the execution state by inspecting `abcCallback.__executed__`. Also remember to reset this flag whenever you want to start over this process.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds interesting. But can I do this inspection in another component?

Comment: @CristianCoroian, you can do wherever you want. It is just a flag on function.

Answer (score 0):

RxJS is a part of Angular.
Maybe you can use it to emit a BehaviourSubject when callback is executed.
After that, you hust have to subscribe to the "event".
RxJS site : https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/
RxJS visual explanations : https://rxmarbles.com/

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";
// By default callback wasn't executed
const executedCallback$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
// Your callback
const myCallback = () => {
  // Each time the callback is executed, the boolean true is emit
  executedCallback$.next(true);
}
// You listen the event
const subscription = executedCallback$.subscribe(executed => {
    // When you subscribe to a Behaviour subject, 
    // you firstly received the actual value, 
    // so you can received the value false if your callback wasn't executed
    if (executed) {
        console.log('My callback was executed');
    }
});
// When you want to stop listening, don't forget to unsubscribe ...
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: As I previously said, I cannot use variables inside the callback, only static ones.

Comment: My question is why can't you ?

Comment: They're undefined.

Comment: Coul'd you spare some of your code with you, it sounds like weird variables are undefined but Objects are ...  
Constants can be exported as object `export const myConst`, functions too ...  
I think there is something else that we can't see without parts of your code ...

Answer (score -1):

You can define a variable outside of the callback and change it in the end of your callback function. The state of that variable will show if the callback was finished.

```
let isCallbackExecuted = false;
let abcCallback = () => {
  // do something
  isCallbackExecuted = true;
};
Promise.resolve().then(abcCallback);
// isCallbackExecuted is true if callback is finished
```

Comment: This thing is not possible, like I said above. The callback is asynchronous and "doesn't know" about the variable, for him being as "undefined".